# Get Latest Created List Item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, client-object-model

I got array of objects that is list items

```
 arr = [{id:"1",name:"item1",created:"Wed Feb 04 2015 03:36:42 GMT+0400"},{id:"2",name:"item2",created:"Sat Feb 04 2015 02:44:39 GMT+0400"}]
```

i want to get the latest created Item
any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item with the biggest ID is the latest created item.

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.id < b.id)
     return -1;
  if (a.id > b.id)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

arr.sort(compare);
var latestItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

You can also compare the dates created in the Compare fuction and it will give the same result.

```
function compare2(a,b) {
  var date1 = new Date(a.created);
  var date2 = new Date(b.created);
  if (date1 < date2)
     return -1;
  if (date1 > date2)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

arr.sort(compare2);
var latestItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
```